# Accessing a text file from a resx file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resx

I previously had code that used `File.ReadAllLines()` to read a text file and store each line into a string array.

However I have decided that the text file would be better stored in a ResX file.

I have added the text file to the ResX file. I know I could use 'resourceManager.GetString' to read the text file but this does not allow me to populate a string array with each line in the text file. How can this be done?

(One thing I tried was was changing the access modifier for the services file to 'public', and then trying to access the contents of the text file but for some reason the auto-generated file failed to build...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.readline.aspx

Comment: Just open that link and let me know if you don't understand the words "Reads a line from the underlying string". String is what you already have, a data you read from your resources. You want this data to be not in single string form, but in array of strings where each element is a line. StringReader is a thing that can be used for converting a single string containing a number of `'\n'`s to multiple strings where each one is text between 2 consequent `'\n'`s. Once again, what's you question?

Comment: Probably, this one is more suitable for you http://www.csharp411.com/c-read-string-line-by-line/